# How Android VNC server receiving key/mouse events from VNC clients

Tags: vnc

How does the Android VNC Server receive key/mouse events from VNC clients? Can any one explain that to me? I am curious to understand.

Answer (score 1):

VNC uses simple protocol, called RFB, you can read more here:

http://www.realvnc.com/docs/rfbproto.pdf

Basically, it's a simple client/server based network protocol, server listens for clients to connect, once a client is connected, clients send mouse/keyboard information to the server using packets. The server parses the messages, and inject key/mouse to the local system.

We released a new VNC Server, VMLite VNC Server, first vnc server working on any android devices:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vmlite.vncserver&hl=en